# Why do we have coarse variants of ktime_get in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel

I was going through the following link:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html

We have both coarse (`ktime_get_coarse()`) and non-coarse (`ktime_get()`) versions.

Which one should we use and when?

It says coarse versions are faster than non-coarse versions.

Do the non-coarse versions read the hardware counter or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q:

> Which one should we use and when?

Seems it's well described on your link.
A:

> These are quicker than the non-coarse versions, but less accurate.

So if you need to be quick and you don't care about accuracy - use coarse (there will be inaccuracy right up to 10ms with 100HZ and just up to 1ms with 1000HZ). If accuracy is a priority, then use non-coarse API.

---

Q:

> Whether the non-coarse versions reads the hardware counter or not?

A:
[`ktime_get()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L747) (unlike the [`ktime_get_coarse()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/include/linux/timekeeping.h#L116)) eventually invokes [`timekeeping_get_delta()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L262()) which reads clocksource with [`tk_clock_read()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L169):

```
static inline u64 tk_clock_read(const struct tk_read_base *tkr)
{
    struct clocksource *clock = READ_ONCE(tkr->clock);

    return clock->read(clock);
}
```

Inside it invokes an appropriate callback for hardware timer to read.
You can search for such callbacks in your sources grepping through the clocksources: `grep -rnI 'read =' drivers/clocksource`.
E.g. [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/drivers/clocksource/h8300_tpu.c#L112) is setting of [`tpu_clocksource_read()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.2/source/drivers/clocksource/h8300_tpu.c#L68).